# How can I print the data of a tree in a string method?

Tags: java, data-structures, avl-tree

I have this method that prints the contents of the **Avl tree**.

```
public String traverseInOrder() {
      return traverseInOrder(root);
}

private String traverseInOrder(TNode<T> node) {
  String Str = "";
    if (node != null) {
      if (node.left != null)
        traverseInOrder(node.left);
        Str +=node;
      if (node.right != null)
        traverseInOrder(node.right);
    }
  return Str;
}
```

There will still be a problem that in this case you are returning **one node** of the Avl tree and **I need all the node** in the Avl tree.
**I don't want to use some kind of void method**
[image]

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Can you share an example of such a tree, the output you're trying to get and the actual result you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the result of the recursion to `Str`. like so:
`Str += traversInOrder(node.left)`
and the same goes for the right one. You also should print the content of the node with `node.value` or whatever your content value name is.

Example:

```
private String traverseInOrder(TNode<T> node) {
  String Str = "";
    if (node != null) {
      if (node.left != null)
        Str += traverseInOrder(node.left);
      Str += node.value;
      if (node.right != null)
        Str += traverseInOrder(node.right);
    }
  return Str;
}
```